# Is there any way in R to speed up this matrix product: A' * B * A (B positive semidefinite)?

Tags: r, linear-algebra

I wonder whether this operation (in R)

```
t(A) %*% B %*% A
```

where B is a positive semidefinite matrix, can be simplified via any *algebraic trick* in order to make it faster (beyond `crossprod(A,B)%*%A`, `Rcpp`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an algebraic trick all you have is that B is positive-semidefinite, i.e. you can find its square root/eigenvalue decomposition.

How you use that fact depends on what you are actually doing.

For instance, maybe you could work with `A` in the eigenbasis of `B` whereby the matrix multiplication you want becomes much more simple. Or perhaps only a few of the eigenvalues of B are significant and you can exclude most of the eigenvectors in your representation of the square root of `B`.

Comment: Could you put an example of how to do this: 'maybe you could work with A in the eigenbasis of B whereby the matrix multiplication you want becomes much more simple'?

Comment: Have a look at `?svd` and `?eigen`. I'm just suggesting replacing `B` with its eigenvalues and premultiplying `A` by `B`'s eigenvector matrix. Whether this makes any sense for speeding up your actual problem is unclear.

Comment: Well, that's the point ;) I think eigendecomposing the B matrix can be slower when it is relatively large.